# Issues with Harvesting COM and GAC DLLs in WiX

Tags: com, wix, gac, heat

I am trying to harvest some dlls which have to be eventually deployed to GAC through installer. When I am calling the heat command as below, I am getting some
errors / warnings as mentioned below.

heat.exe dir "D:\InstallTest" -cg \"MyCompGgroup\" -dr MY_DIR -gg -g1 -srd -sfrag -var var.OutDir -out "D:\InstallTest\MyComps.wxs"

1. Could not harvest data from a file that was expected to be a SelfReg DLL. If this file does not support SelfReg, you can ignore this warning. Otherwise, this error detail may be helpful to diagnose the failure. Unable to load the file.
2. Could not harvest data from a file that was expected to be an assembly. If this file is not an assembly, you can ignore this warning. Otherwise, this error detail may be helpful to diagnose the failure. Could not load the file or assembly 'Assembly Name' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Actually, the files which are being mentioned as missing, are actually present in the same directory.

I am also trying to harvest some COM components with the same heat command as above. I am getting the below warning

Ignoring the Registry key 'Interface{Guid}\Something', it has already been added to the Component 'cmpGuid'. The registry value '{Guid}' will not be harvested.

For one of the COM components, the heat command even fails with the following error.

```
heat.exe : error HEAT0001 : '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.

Exception Type: System.ArgumentException

Stack Trace:
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(Int32 ch, Char* pDst, Boolean entitize)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteAttributeTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriterIndent.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(String localName, String value)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.Class.OutputXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.TypeLib.OutputXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.File.OutputXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.Component.OutputXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.Directory.OutputXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.DirectoryRef.OutputXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.Fragment.OutputXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.Wix.OutputXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Tools.Heat.Run(String[] args)
```

Can anyone please help?

Note: I already checked in this site itself for some of the above issues, but couldn't find a good solution. I also checked the link below, but it didn't seem to help. I am not even able to debug heat.exe though I have the source in VS2017. Any help would be appreciated.

https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4108

Comment: I've had some trouble with individual self-reg dlls and heat. In the end I had to use registry monitoring software to monitor the registry before and after running regsrv and manually write the appropriate registry definitions in my wxs file.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Unfortunately, I may not be able to do that, since in my case, the registration and removal has to be dynamic and also, there could be new COM components as well.